# how to create new directory everyday having its name as current date

Tags: java, logging, timestamp, directory, logfiles

```
Date dir = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String baseDir = "/home/gaurav/usr/logs/ESBegin/";
String newDir = createDateBasedDirectory(baseDir, dir);

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog1");  
FileHandler fh;  

try {  

    // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
    fh = new FileHandler(newDir+"/data.log");  
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

    // the following statement is used to log any messages  
    logger.info(stringifiedJson);  

} catch (SecurityException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

this will create a folder of todays date but i want to create new folder for everyday and store the log file in new folder....means everyday's folder must have that day's log file
i have following method to create a folder

```
 public static String createDateBasedDirectory(String baseDirectory, Date argDate) {
        String newDir = null;

        if (baseDirectory != null && argDate != null) {
            try {
                String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                String date = dateFormatter.format(argDate);
                File f = new File(baseDirectory);
                File files[] = f.listFiles();
                String dir = null;
                int baseDirLength = baseDirectory.length();
                int checkingLength = baseDirLength + format.length() + 3;

                int maxSeqNo = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                        dir = files[i].toString();
                        if (dir.length() == checkingLength) {
                            String existingDirDate = dir.substring(baseDirLength, baseDirLength + 10);

                            if (date.equalsIgnoreCase(existingDirDate)) {
                                int dirSeqNo = 
                                    Integer.parseInt(dir.substring(baseDirLength + 11, baseDirLength + 10 + 3));

                                if (dirSeqNo > maxSeqNo) {
                                    maxSeqNo = dirSeqNo;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                String currSeq = "" + (maxSeqNo + 1);
                if (currSeq.length() == 1) {
                    currSeq = "0" + currSeq;
                }

                newDir = baseDirectory + date;
                new File(newDir).mkdir();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return newDir;
    }
```

what should i change if in want to create a new folder everyday

Comment: You can have a look at some schedulers. Spring batch has one.

Comment: You could create a little method that returnes the folder of the day at a log attempt, or just creates it if it does not already exist.

Comment: configure your logger instead ! example for log4j: `log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`

Comment: @HalayemAnis i don't want log files name to be change i just want to create new folder of every day.... log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender this will create new log file

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functionality of your logging framework to do so. For example use [Log4J's RollingFileAppender](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-2-rollingfileappender-example/).

You can use the `fileName` parameter to create new directories. From the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender):

> fileName: The name of the file to write to. If the file, or any of its parent directories, do not exist, they will be created.

Comment: but i want new folder which has name of current date to be created every day not log file....

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a new folder every day, where a new log file (with always the same name) is created? That would be possible with the RollingFileAppender.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the directory for the current day exists, then create it if it doesn't exist or simply return it if it does exist.

```
/*
 * to make sure everyone knows what's going on 
 * name this method like getOrCreateDailyLogDirectory
 */
public static String createDateBasedDirectory(String baseDirectory, Date argDate) {
    String newDir = null;

    if (baseDirectory != null && argDate != null) {
        try {
            String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            String date = dateFormatter.format(argDate);
            // check if the directory exists:
            String todaysLogDir = baseDirectory + "\\" + date; // create the path as String
            // then create a Path (java.nio, alternatives possible)
            Path todaysDirectoryPath = Paths.get(todaysLogDir);
            // and check if this Path exists
            if (Files.exists(todaysDirectoryPath) {
                // if present, just return it in order to write (into) a log file there
                return todaysDirectoryPath.toUri().toString();
            } else {
                // create it the way you want and return the path as String
                ...
            }
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return newDir;
}
```

Doing it this (or a similar) way always returns the directory for the current day and creates it before once a day on first log attempt.

Comment: else {
         
              new File(newDir).mkdir();
             return todaysDirectoryPath.toUri().toString();
             }         like this??

Comment: For example... yes... just take your code that creates the directory.

Comment: return todaysDirectoryPath.toUri().toString();   return this?? or return newDir.toString();

Comment: That `else` block handles the case of the first attempt to log, so no directory exists and you need to create it. I think you can return `newDir.toString()` but I am not sure. Just try it... Best practice would be returning the `String` or `Uri.toString()` you used for creation of the directory.